# Filter abstract classes from list

Tags: c#

I have a `new List<AbstractClass> ()` that contains some different implementations. I want to filter out some implementations due to specific conditions. How to do it properly?

```
1) if (condition1 && type is Implementation1) ...

2) if (condition2 && implementation.Name == "Implementation 1") ...

3) if (condition3 && implementation.Type == EnumType.Type1) ...
```

I think 1) is bad, 2) does not work at compile time 3) may be good?

Any suggestions for other desgin?

(coudn't post it on programmers.SE because of ban)

Edit:
More details. Imagine abstract class (or interface):

```
class abstract MessagePrinter
{ 
    void Print (string message);
}
```

and class `ConsolePrinter : MessagePrinter` which prints message on console. So when due to some reasons I want to stop printing message on console, I need to remove that implementation from my `List<MessagePrinter>`. But what if ConsolePrinter is wrapped using `UpperCaseMessagePrinter`?

```
class UpperCaseMessagePrinter : MessagePrinter
{
    public UpperCaseMessagePrinter (MessagePrinter source) { /* ... */ };

    void Print (string message)
    {
        source.Print (message.ToUpper());
    }
 }
```

All that type checking will be useless. Solution #3 with enum helps a bit, but is not perfect :/

Comment: can you list the reasons you would need that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `.OfType` extension method for filtering.

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}

var listOfBase = new List<Base>();
// ...
var enumerableOfDerived = listOfBase.OfType<Derived>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the types are known during compile time then I would opt for using the `typeof(...)` operator.

If the types are not known during compile time then you would have to check the `System.Type` via `Object.GetType()`.